# Wordpress <!..more..>

Tags: wordpress, tags

Can the `<!..more..>` tag me used to make a start and end point, something like below

```
<h2>Post Details</h2>

<!--more Just the text in here to appear on the home page nothing else above or below. more!-->
```

All I want is the small text to appear on the home page, however using the tag in the traditional way, seen below means the header 'Post Details' appears on the home page as well

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Details</h2>
</div>
This is small text that should appear on the home page without showing the header

<!..more-->
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking, but my gut feeling is *No*.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution. It was to simply use `the_excerpt();` which ignores everything but the text such as headers